# Devise/CanCan - Restricted Content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise, cancan

Building a rails B2B application that will have various users. I'm pretty clear on restricting access for internal staff using Devise and CanCan but I want to be able to give suppliers and customers their own login as well. Customer will be fairly simple, however, I want to ensure the supplier (label) login enables them to view and amend their own product and sales data only.

The model is roughly:

```
User (as setup by Devise)
Label [has_many releases]
Release [belongs_to label / has_many products]
Product [belongs_release / has_many tracks]
Track [belongs_product]
```

I'm guessing I could add in a label_id field on the user model and associate that way but I need internal users (and customers) to have access to view all label data. I also need to allow a label to have many users.

Would it simply be a case of defining a 'label' role via Cancan that enforces the use of a label_id in the the views? If that's the correct approach how do I then lock down the content to that label_id in my controllers/views? Role based if statements?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you'd first have to do is define some CanCan roles, like supplier, customer and staff, and then create an interstitial controller to handle the forking:

```
class CheckingController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @path = case user.role
      when 'supplier'
        supplier_path
      when 'customer'
        customer_path
      when 'staff'
        staff_path
      else
        admin_sign_in_path #or whatever
    end

    redirect_to @path     
  end
end
```

Then in your `routes.rb` file you can send users to either the root or index action of your controller by first sending them to `CheckingController#index` which will redirect based on your CanCan roles.

Comment: Ok, many thanks for the pointers, will have a go and see how I get on.